# Hibernate composite key with foregin key to another table - How to avoid circular reference?

Tags: hibernate, primary-key, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I have a Student table with an auto generated id as primary key and one to many mapping to Phone table.

My Phone table has a composite key PhonePK with phone number and the foreign key id to the Student table as primary keys.

If I do phonePk.setStudent it works but I really don't want to do this. How can I achieve this? If its not achievable, I would like to settle with setting the student id but not the whole student object. How do I do this? Would really appreciate if someone can give an insight on this.

**student.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Student implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String fName;

private String lName;

private String mName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Set<Phone> phones;

/**
 * @return the fName
 */
public String getfName() {
return fName;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
return id;
}

/**
 * @return the lName
*/
public String getlName() {
return lName;
}

/**
 * @return the mName
 */
public String getmName() {
return mName;
}

/**
* @return the phones
 */
public Set<Phone> getPhones() {
return phones;
}

/**
 * @param fName
 *            the fName to set
 */
public void setfName(final String fName) {
   this.fName = fName;
}

/**
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(final int id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @param lName
 *            the lName to set
 */
public void setlName(final String lName) {
this.lName = lName;
}

/**
 * @param mName
 *            the mName to set
*/
public void setmName(final String mName) {
this.mName = mName;
}

/**
 * @param phones
 *            the phones to set
 */
public void setPhones(final Set<Phone> phones) {
this.phones = phones;
}

}
```

**Phone.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Phone implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
 private PhonePK PK;

private String color;

/**
 * @return the color
 */
public String getColor() {
return color;
}

public PhonePK getPK() {
return PK;
}

/**
 * @param color
 *            the color to set
 */
public void setColor(final String color) {
this.color = color;
}

public void setPK(final PhonePK pK) {
PK = pK;
}



}
```

**PhonePK.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Embeddable
@SuppressWarnings({ "serial" })
public class PhonePK implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private Student student;

private String phoneNumber;

public String getPhoneNumber() {
return phoneNumber;
}

public Student getStudent() {
return student;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(final String phoneNumber) {
this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public void setStudent(final Student student) {
this.student = student;
}



}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

 public static void main(final String args[]) {

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
Transaction transaction = null;

configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Phone.class);
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Student student = new Student();
student.setfName("Bob");
student.setlName("Buster");

Set<Phone> phones = new LinkedHashSet<Phone>();
Phone phone = new Phone();
phone.setColor("Black");
PhonePK phonePK = new PhonePK();
phonePK.setPhoneNumber("1111111111");
phonePK.setStudent(student); // Do not do this? But won't work (id cannot be null  
error) if commented out??
phone.setPK(phonePK);
phones.add(phone);

student.setPhones(phones);

try {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(student);
    transaction.commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    transaction.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    session.close();
}

}
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
<hibernate-configuration>  
<session-factory>  
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">cosmo99</property>  
<property    
name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ops_suite</property>  
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">cosmo-security</property>  
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>  
 </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: If you don't want to have circular references just have the phones set into the students. If you aim to link the phones with the students, you must have the whole student entity.